# Ascending descending with one link button in php laravel

Tags: php, sorting, laravel

I want to order ascending and descending data with one link. fist click make ascending order and second click make descending .

I'm developing with Laravel Framework.

I'm successfully developed ascending function with link request. Here is my code >>

View File >>

```
<th width="18%"><a href="{!! URL::route('cms.place.filterByAsc', ['word'=>'name']) !!}" class="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit">Name</a></th>
```

Controller >>

```
public function filterByAsc($word)
{
    $places = $this->place->ascendingBy($word);
    return view('cms.place.index',compact('places')); 
}
```

Now , I have no idea how to sent get_request with the same link . Please show me the way.

Thanks and respect to all .

Answer (score 2):

instead of segements, i would have used a query here since it is much more applicable here.

e.g. `?sort=asc` will retrieve the results in ascending order and `?sort=desc` will retrieve the result in descending order.

for the link,

```
<a href="{{route('home')}}
    ?sort=@if(Request::input('sort','asc')=='asc') desc @else asc @endif">reverse order
</a>
```

if you really want to stick to segments way, then you may opt to the following:

### Routes.php:

```
get('test/{sort}',['as' => 'test', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'])
->where('sort', 'asc|desc');
```

### Controller:

```
public function index($sort)
{
    return view('someview', ['data' => $this->model->index(), 'sort' => $sort]);
}
```

### View::

```
<?php $reverse = ($sort == 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';?>
<a href="{{route('home',[$reverse])}}">{{$reverse}}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I understand about your logic and really appreciate it .
I tried to code like that >>
..
..
'<a href="{!! URL::route('cms.place.filterByAsc', ['word'=>'name']) !!}
    ?sort=@if(Request::input('sort','asc')=='asc') desc @else asc @endif">reverse order
</a>'
...
...
It didn't work . Please tell me more detail . Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I understand about your logic and really appreciate it . I tried to code like that >> .. .. 
..
`<a href="{!! URL::route('cms.place.filterByAsc', ['word'=>'name']) !!}
    ?sort=@if(Request::input('sort','asc')=='asc') desc @else asc @endif">reverse order
</a>`
...
 Please tell me more detail . Thanks